# PHP: Sending CSS into head instead of body (Joomla extension)

Tags: php, css, joomla, slideshow, joomla-extensions

I'm using AutsonSlideShow extension for Joomla 1.7 which works just fine. The plugin has its downsides tho, as it writes **CSS** right into the **body** of the index.php file. I would like to change this for validation reasons. <sup>(There's more validation errors in it btw, if anybody maybe wants to double check that)</sup>

*Is there any commands or ways to send the whole part of that css-code (includes php variables) to the **head** instead or make it available externally?*

Here is an excerpt from the default.php which is the file that writes into my index.

```
<style type="text/css">
.box_skitter_large<?php echo $module->id;?> {width:<?php echo $slidewidth;?>px;height:<?php echo $slideheight; ?>px;}
<?php echo $margin;?>
.box_skitter_small {width:200px;height:200px;}
.box_skitter {border:<?php echo $border;?>px solid <?php echo $bordercolor;?>; background:<?php echo $backgroundcolor;?>}
</style>
```

It's just a cropdown of the whole part, but it's representative. If you check the sourcecode of [this demo site of the plugin](http://demo.autson.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=5) you can see the problem.

Greetings, Marian

Comment: FYI: It's actually faster to have all the CSS in <style>, since the browser won't have to send extra requests for the CSS files. Worth to think about. Not tested, but try looking into this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/site-performance/16524

Comment: Thats totally fine with me as long as it gets put in the head section, where it actually should be imho.

Comment: @Zar but then you'd have a huge multiplication of lines for each single page (1 request, but more to read). Marian can you post a link to the site? What are the validation errors?

Comment: @utopicam How would it be more for the browser to read? It still reads the "code", no matter if it is in another request or not. Same amount of code, less requests.

Comment: @utopicam my site is still local, but if you validate the link in my post you will get the same validation errors you would if you implemented the extension on your site.

Comment: @Zar - CSS inside style tags cannot take advantage of any browser caching and will need to be served with the page every time thereby increasing the size of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ob_start();
?>

YOUR CSS HERE

<?php
$style = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration($style);
```